# Substitute strings by dictionary in text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text that contains snippets like

```
'Data: ["ID1", "ID5"]'
```

Actually, these are JSON arrays of random size.

I have a dictionary `D` that maps ID to integer. For instance, `D["ID1"]=23`, `D["ID5"]=7`. And I need to replace all these IDs with their dictionary values. So the result must be

`Data: [23, 7]`

I cannot just replace all the occurences of `"ID1"` with `23` in the text, because only IDs in `Data` arrays must be replaced.

I have created a regexp

```
r = re.compile(r"Data: \[(\"(\w+)\")(, \"(\w+)\")*\]")
```

that allows me to find these `Data` snippets. But I do not know how to make a replace...

```
iter = r.finditer(str)
for m in iter:
    # whats next?
```

Comment: If you use `json.loads` to load the JSON data into a python data structure, what type of python structure do you get? Please post a sample of that python structure

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: `json.loads` won't load that: `Data` isn't a quoted string.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I am aware of that, and that therefore OP is likely not showing us the entire input. Rather than argue "show us the proper input", I figured having a proper python structure to work with would make everyone's life easier